# Take <span> class and put in <a> attribute jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html like this.

```
<span class="gallery-open-item year-icon-Yes 2010">
<a href="/year/none">
</a>
</span>
```

I need to check using jQuery if `span.gallery-open-item` has `year-icon-Yes` class, and if so take the next (for this example is 2010) class and place it in the `href` attribute like this:

```
<a href="/year/2010"/>
```

All this I need in jQuery or JavaScript.

I have done some experiments but I can't take 2010 to normal javascript variable.
Any ideas?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: To what end? My "there has to be a better way" sense is tingling.

Comment: One thing, classnames in CSS should not begin with a number, Can you instead start it with something else? Maybe `y-2010` ?

Comment: Yes there is no problem. I can start with y-.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('span.gallery-open-item.year-icon-Yes > a').each(function(i, elem) {
  $.each($(elem).parent().attr('class').split(' '), function(j, klass) {
    // NOTE: use /^y-([\d]*)$/ if years are prefixed with y-
    if (year = klass.match(/^([\d]*)$/))
      $(elem).attr('href', $(elem).attr('href').replace('none', year[1]));
  });
});
```

This would iterate over every A tag beneath your SPAN tags and fetch the classes from each parent, search these for a number and replace the "next" part.

**Update:** Added comments for the case you switch to prefixed years.

**Update 2:** Now tested and working (using Prototype usually *sigh*).

Comment: Amended my code for the selector to find only direct descendents as parent() only looks up the direct ascendent. You may switch to closest("a") instead of parent() if other behaviour is intended.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach. Tested, working.

```
$('.gallery-open-item.year-icon-Yes').each(function(){
    that = this;
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    $.each(classes, function(i, val) {
        if (val.match(/^y-/gi)) {
            $('a', that).attr('href', function(){
                return this.href.replace('none', val.split('-')[1]);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Assumes this markup:

```
<span class="gallery-open-item year-icon-Yes y-2010">
<a href="/year/none/">
    Test
</a>
</span>
```

Comment: You are using attr() to access 'href' for reading but not for writing (which may be unportable between browsers).

Comment: hurikhan77, it is my understanding that the jQuery library does work under the hood to make calls to `getAttribute` for browsers which require it. Does that alay your concern? Take a look at the source: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js

Comment: @art well not really as that's not the concern. My concern is about the `this.href.replace()` call which should consequently be `$(this).attr('href').replace()`

Comment: "may be unportable between browsers" you say, what browsers?

Comment: @art the word is "may", I cannot currently think of a browser. However, for consistency: Why use ` attr('href')`  in one place and then ` .href` in another?

Comment: hurikhan, take a look at the way `this.id` and `this.title` are used on the jQuery documentation page for `attr()`. http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it. First, we select the `span` tags that have both the classes `gallery-open-item` and `year-icon-Yes`. Then, for each of them we're going to get an array of classes that the `span` tag has. I loop over the class names, and check for the first one that is a number. Finally, modify the `a` tag inside the `span` to set the desired url.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.gallery-open-item.year-icon-Yes').each(function() {
        var classNames = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
        for (var i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++)
        {
            if (!isNaN(classNames[i]))
            {
                var year = classNames[i];
                $(this).find('a').attr('href', '/year/'+year);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit**: Based on the comments that class names should not start with a number, it's pretty easy to make this work for class names of the form `y-xxxx`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.gallery-open-item.year-icon-Yes').each(function() {
        var classNames = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
        for (var i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
            var year = classNames[i].substring(2);
            if (!isNaN(year)) {
                $(this).find('a').attr('href', '/year/' + year);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes it is, but it's not DRY... You'd have to modify the "/year/" prefix in two places if you change the URL scheming later... If you don't dry this you may wonder about strange bugs coming up suddenly. Don't believe you think of every bit in your code when applying changes weeks later.